# WP Blog Publish to Facebook Profile - publishing to my Personal FB (should be to FanPage

Tags: wordpress, blogs, facebook-page

Am using Wordpress for my blog.  Have "Simple Facebook Connect" as a plugin in order to publish (must click "Publish to your Facebook profile") to Facebook. I have all the info entered correctly (NOT REALLY), because it is publishing to my FB page.

The problem is, It is publishing to my FB page Not my Fanpage.  I Need for it to publish to my Fanpage NOT my personal page.  I have spent too many hours trying to solve this, reading forums, etc. and have not found a solution, which is probably very simple and I will feel really silly when I get this done.

I would love to keep my personal friends on my FB and my business/students on my fanpage.

Thank you in advance for the help/guidance.  I am very new at this and would appreciate your feedback to be KISS (Keep it Simple Silly) friendly.  I already have a migraine.

Thanks again!